# Does the Arduino have any specific cooling requirements?

Tags: arduino, safety, cooling

If I were to encase my Arduino in a sealed case with no ventilation, would this be an issue? What about if I were to pot the Arduino in epoxy, would that pose a cooling issue?

Comment: In a bit of a rush so cannot write a full answer, but search for "Conformal Coating"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only time I've ever run into a cooling issue in regards to an Arduino project was then I was running a TLC5940 LED driver chip, and I had it wired up wrong, and it melted the solderless breadboard. So, that's not even related to the Arduino directly.  I've never run or even heard of a circuit that was wired up correctly make the Arduino get even kind of warm at all.

If your circuit runs cool to the touch and you're never ever ever ever going to need to get to it, it should be okay to encase it in epoxy. Never say never, but if things are running normally, it should be okay.

Also consider alternatives to epoxy; air/water tight cases are possible to obtain if your project is water/moisture/dirt based. If buoyancy is a concern, you can always add steel plating or lead shot in the case.

Comment: One thing to look at for temperature is the voltage regulator if you use lots of current. Air is actually a insulator (think double pane windows) so when you coat it in other surfaces it might actually be **cooler**. (I don't know what the thermal properties of epoxy are and it is so little, you probably couldn't tell.) Be careful not to coat the headers so you can make adjustments. If it is underwater, remember water conducts so any part not coated is linked. For this reason, a case is the best solution.